# Black flash Android html5 video on autoplay

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, video

I have an issue on Android with a html5 video.
Before the video starts to autoplay I experience a quick black flash (few ms), then the video play nicely and loop correctly.

```
<video
  src="intro.mp4"
  poster="intro-firstframe.png"
  autoplay
  loop
  muted>
    <img src="no-video.png"/>
</video>
```

The poster seems to never been applied and I wonder why so?
I tried everything from setting a fixed height and width to my element, different poster, different videos but nothing change, the black flash is still here.

Currently I'm listening to the `loadeddata` event and do a trick of `display:none` and setTimeout with my video but this is really hacky..

For info, I'm using React and Cordova.

Any clean solution?

Comment: (for info, I ended up using.. gif. Haha, way easier for my case. But still interested on a valid answer)